# Appcelerator iOS video starts playing again after 2, 4 seconds. How can it be avoided

Tags: ios, iphone, video-streaming, appcelerator, appcelerator-alloy

I have an iOS(iPhone, iPad) app. It plays videos from a remote url. It's created in **Appcelerator**.

I show a loader till the video loads and then remove it. But when the video starts playing for the first time(by hitting the native play button on the video player) it runs for 2 to 4 seconds and then again starts playing from the beginning.

Below is the XML code for the player

```
<VideoPlayer id="videoPlayer" onLoad="VideoLoad" onPlaybackstate="PlayBack" 
onComplete="videoCompleteLoad" onDurationavailable="SaveVideoDuration" ns="Ti.Media">   
                </VideoPlayer>
```

Appcelerator **SDK version** used is **6.0.1.GA**

Answer (score 0):

This issue has nothing to do with appcelerator SDK. I tried with my remote URL and it worked fine for me. Considering your issue is occurring due to the `autoplay` property of the `videoplayer`. You need to set the `autoplay` to `false`.

```
<VideoPlayer id="videoPlayer" autoplay="false" onLoad="VideoLoad" onPlaybackstate="PlayBack" 
onComplete="videoCompleteLoad" onDurationavailable="SaveVideoDuration" ns="Ti.Media">   
</VideoPlayer>
```

**Good Luck, Cheers**

Comment: Thank you for replying A A Sebastian. I tried doing that but the issue persists. I kept autoplay false in the .tss file. Strangely when I set it to true the restart happens rarely but it does happen.

Comment: Could you please share the link of the video you trying to play, because this will solve the problem. What actually happens here is that when '**autoplay**' is true. It starts playing to the video as soon as it gets the buffer. But when you manually click on '**play**' button to forcefully start the video. It happens to trigger the '**autoplay**' function after a while. So for now ** Please send the Video URL** so that I can give it a try.

Comment: sorry replying late. It would be difficult to share the video url on the forum I'll still check. But a strange thing I observed that when I lower down the SDK version to 5.5.1 the issue gets resolved. It occurs after 6.x SDK builds